# GetValue() from a variable field inside a class

Tags: c#, fieldinfo

Suppose I have a simple class:

```
 public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour {
      public Vector3 myVector3;
 }
```

Now I want to iterate through an the fields of an instance of this class and to access the fields of this field (Field-Ception!) and assign the values to variables of the right Type, effectively "wrapping" the field so it can be serialized. Here, I would reach the Vector3 field "myVector3" and upon reaching it, go over it's fields and assign their Values to three floats (what a Vector3 is made up of).

Problem? fieldinfo.`GetValue()` returns the Type `MonoField`! If I use fieldinfo.`FieldType`, it returns `Vector3`, but that doesn't help me as I need the Value :/

```
TestScript myTestScript;//an instance of the MonoBehaviour class
const BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;
 //the fields... only 1 in this case (myVector3)
 FieldInfo[] fields = myTestScript.GetType().GetFields(flags);

 //store Type...
 var tp = myTestScript.GetType();
 //iterate over the fields
 foreach FieldInfo field in fields) {

      if (field != null) {
           //check if the field is of Type Vector3
           if(field.FieldType == typeof(Vector3)) {
                const BindingFlags flags_v3 = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;
                //the following will give me an array of FieldInfo 
                //with Type MonoField, but I need the 
                //actual x, y and z (floats) fields!
                FieldInfo[] fields_v3 = field.GetType().GetFields(flags);
                //added with edit:
                foreach(FieldInfo field_v3 in fields_v3) {
                    object value = field_v3 .GetValue(field)//the line in question... Since field.GetType returns MonoFields instead of the Vector3, I can not access the Vector3 Type's x y z fields/values.
                }
           }
      }
 }
```

Comment: I don't see you calling `GetValue` here..

Comment: I advise removing `BindingFlags.Static` from all flags, if you want to serialize instances only.

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer and thanks for the feedback. I didn't include the actual GetValue lines because I feel like the problem is already withing the field.GetType().GetFields() line, giving me the MonoField array instead of the x y z floats a Vector3 has. not saying it's a bug or something, just not the thing I need because obviously I can't use GetValue with a MonoField to get the wanted x y z floats. I added the foreach loop to make things clearer (hopefully). BindingFlags.static has been removed as recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`field.GetType()` returns the type of the actual reflection object, which is `MonoField`, in this case. Use `field.FieldType`, this property contains the type of the value stored in the field itself:

```
FieldInfo[] fields_v3 = field.FieldType.GetFields(flags);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will try it out immediately. I wasn't aware that this could be "chained" together like this.
Edit: Yes, indeed it solved the first part of my problem. I now have the right fieldinfo array (x, y, z). However, I'm still in the dark when it comes to using GetValue:

Comment: `code object value = field_v3.GetValue(field)`

Throws an error:

`ArgumentException: Field 'x' defined on type 'Vector3' is not a field on the target object which is of type 'MonoField'.`

Comment: @Cherno Under foreach: `object vector = field.GetValue(myTestScript);` Then `object value = field_v3.GetValue(vector);` Fields are specific to a type, not an instance.

Comment: A thousand thanks to you! I suspected something like your solution but couldn't get the syntax right. Now it works aas intended. Thanks again!